# conver xml using xslt node as tag, text as value

Tags: xml, xslt

i would like convert xml, that:

tag is the name of current node (this, i made myself)

the value betwen nodes was betwen my new tags

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<IDataXMLCoder version="1.0">
  <record javaclass="xxx">
    <record name="result" javaclass="yyy">
      <value name="errorCode">0</value>
      <value name="errorDesc">OK</value>
    </record>
  </record>
</IDataXMLCoder>
```

And i would like to convert to something like that:

```
<IDataXMLCoder>
    <record>
        <result>
            <errorCode>0</errorCode>
            <errorDesc>OK</errorDesc>
        </result>
    </record>
</IDataXMLCoder>
```

As you see,

```
name="errorCode"
```

is now the name of node. Value of this node  is

```
0
```

I wrote so far that code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>--> <!--po usunieciu nie bedzie wciec-->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
                          "*/@*[contains('|javaclass|version|',
                      concat('|',name(),'|')
                      )
            ]"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{current()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i got that:

```
<IDataXMLCoder>
  <record>
    <record>
<result>result</result>
      <value>
<errorCode>errorCode</errorCode>0</value>
      <value>
<errorDesc>errorDesc</errorDesc>OK</value>
    </record>
  </record>
</IDataXMLCoder>
```

So, how can i turn it into what i want? Thanks, for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet that achieves the described result for the posted input sample:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If that does not suffice then you need to explain your requirements in more detail.

Comment: very nice... and i was working on it for whole day :) this is very short. I'm impressed. I got this excercise on my summer internship. First time i hear about xslt, it's hard for me to wade through this topic :)

Comment: @Martin Honnen can you explain me the last lines of your code (second template)? I will appreciate for this.

Comment: The stylesheet has two templates, the second one applies to all element nodes that have a `name` attribute. For each such element a result element is created with the name taken from the `name` attribute value, then the child nodes are processed with `apply-templates` (so that they are either copied by the first template if they don't have a name attribute or they are processed recursively by the second template).